# How to add a user to a running approval process?

Tags: approval-process

Imagine 1000 Contacts x are in Approval Process z. How would I then add a user 'Ryan' to the existing approval processes to help the approver 'Carla' finish all these?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The question is not clear. Is Carla an approver ? And who is Ryan ?

Comment: Carla is an approver, I edited the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: It's not clear yet. Who is Ryan ? Is Ryan also an approver ? And do you want to share the approval requests between them ?

Comment: Ryan is just another user. Ryan is not an approver yet, but Ryan should be added to the EXISTING records, which are currently in an approval process. Not the future ones.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Seems its SFDC Limitation. You can not add user to approval process.

Limitations
There is a limit of 30 steps.

1. There is a limit of 25 approvers per step.
2. You can't create outbound messages for approval processes on
       junction objects.

> 3. After an approval process is activated, you can't add, delete, or
>          change the order of the steps or change reject or skip behavior for
>          that process, even if you make the process inactive.

Comment: Are you sure "behavior" means also, that you can't add a new approver? Because I think what they are saying there, is that you can't change the logic. I just want to add a new approver

Comment: You can transfer to other approver by going setup>Mass Transfer Approval Processes. But i don't find any thing which suggest to add new approver.

Comment: Maybe nothing that way, but programmatically I think this should be somehow possible

Comment: I think you can do it through apex. You can look into this link. http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/dynamic-approval-process-based-on-the-apex-and-trigger/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a new step to an existing approval process until you deactivate it and clone to add a new step. But you can always add new approvers to an existing step in the active approval process.[image: Existing Approval Process]

Just click on Edit and follow the steps. In Step 3 you click on "Add Row" to add new users as Approvers.[image: Step 3 of Approval Process]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Like this you add it to the process in general, but it doesn't apply to current records which are in the approval process and that is my problem

Comment: If you add an approver to the next approval step and the contact is still in the previous approval step, then it works without any issues.

Comment: It is about the step the contact is CURRENTLY in. That is the problem.

Comment: Then I think we have to go for Mass Transfer Approval Processes only.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Ryan as the delegated approver on Carla's user record. Then run the following code for mass approval of requests (Not a full working code)

```
    List<ProcessInstanceWorkItem> workItemList = [Select p.ProcessInstance.Status,
p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId,p.ProcessInstanceId,p.OriginalActorId,p.Id,p.ActorId
From ProcessInstanceWorkitem p where p.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :  "Carla's id"];

    for(ProcessInstanceWorkItem item: workItemList){
       item.ActorId  = 'Ryan's Id';
     }
    update workItemList;
```